# Complie form fails with eric6 under Anaconda

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, eric-ide

Trying to compile form(dialog) in Eric6 IDE. But got compilation fail error. Log said "pyuic4: System cannot find path" (If you are using Chinese system, switch encoding in Python page in Eric config)

I am using Anaconda python3 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

Due to unknown reason, the path string in 
`C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\pyuic.bat` is wrong:

```
@"C:\aroot\stage\python" "C:\aroot\stage\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Change `\aroot\stage` to the right path in you system and it will work

also refer to this page in Chinese:
http://snowdaily.pixnet.net/blog/post/65607269-%E5%B0%87-.ui-%E4%BD%88%E5%B1%80%E6%AA%94%E8%BD%89%E6%8F%9B%E6%88%90-.py-python-%E7%A8%8B%E5%BC%8F%E6%AA%94